# How to execute one of the two queries based on a Condition in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, jdeveloper

I have to run one of the two queries through a ViewObject in Oracle Adf. It's based on a condition that I may or may not enter a group Code. The first query handles the scenario when the user will not input any parameters and the second query handles the scenario when user inputs a  Group Code. depending on whether user inputs parameter or not, I have to run on the following queries. I will be using only one View Object.

1.SELECT   IIM.index_num
        ,IIM.description
FROM     inv_item_mst    IIM
WHERE    IIM.group_cd    IN   (:GroupCode1,:GroupCode2,:GroupCode3,:GroupCode4,:GroupCode5,:GroupCode6,:GroupCode7)
AND      IIM.generic_cd  LIKE NVL(:generic_cd_param,'%')
AND      IIM.supplier_cd LIKE NVL(:supplier_cd_param,'%')

2.SELECT   IIM.index_num
        ,IIM.description
FROM     inv_item_mst    IIM
WHERE    IIM.group_cd =:groupCd

Comment: Why will you be using only one view object?

Comment: It has to be one view object I suppose because the first query's output is handled by the application. That is, the GroupCode1...GroupCode7 are jhs parameters which takes it's values from user login. Now, there are 7 possible group codes and user A is allowed to access Groups 1, 2 and 3. So, he has a choice of 1, 2 and 3 and he may select any. Depending on this selection the second query should execute and should give me only index numbers belong to the inputted group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are selecting the same columns from the same table just combine the statements with an OR condition in the WHERE clause checking if the *:groupCd* value is present:

```
SELECT IIM.index_num, IIM.description
FROM inv_item_mst IIM
WHERE (:groupCd IS NOT NULL AND IIM.group_cd =:groupCd)
OR (:groupCd IS NULL AND
    IIM.group_cd IN (:GroupCode1,:GroupCode2,:GroupCode3,:GroupCode4,:GroupCode5,:GroupCode6,:GroupCode7)
    AND IIM.generic_cd LIKE NVL(:generic_cd_param,'%')
    AND IIM.supplier_cd LIKE NVL(:supplier_cd_param,'%')
   )
```